# Jump to the wrong position when perform a far jump operation in x86 real mode

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, bootloader, real-mode

first apologize for my poor english : )
I'm now developing a simple bootloader for my toy os, but i got stucked in the very early stage.
That is i want to move the bootsector from 0x7c00 to 0x90000 for the new kernel movement, but when i finished copy and perform a far jump to the new position (in 0x90000), it jump to the wrong position.
Here is my code:

```
    .code16
    .text
/* first move bootsector to 0x90000 for the kernel move */
start:
    mov $0x07c0, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds

    mov %dl, boot_dirver            /* save boot dirver number */

    mov $0x9000, %ax
    mov %ax, %es
    mov $256, %cx
    xor %si, %si
    xor %di, %di
    rep
    movsw

    jmp $0x9000, $go
go:
    /* now we are in the 0x90000
    mov %ax, %cs
    mov %ax, %ds
    mov %ax, %es
    mov %ax, %ss
    mov $0xffff, %sp

    mov $20, %cx
    mov $msg_boot, %ax
    call print_msg
    
/* ======================================================
 *  load kernel using bios int 0x13, ah = 0x42
 *  kernel size: 128kb, kernel position: 0x10000
 *  read twice, 64kb per operation in size (64K boundary --> 80h sectors)
 * ====================================================== */
load_kernel:
    mov $0x42, %ah
    mov boot_dirver, %dl
    mov $packet, %si
    int $0x13
    jc fail

    addw $0x1000, packet.destination.segment
    addw $0x0080, packet.start
    int $0x13
    jc fail

    
/* ======================================================
 *  detect memory map using bios int 0x15, ax = 0xe820
 *  put the number of discriptors in 0x8000 (4bytes in size)
 *  followed with the array of descriptors
 * ====================================================== */
detect_mem:
    movl $0, 0x8000
    xor %ebx, %ebx
    mov $0x8000+4, %di
do_detect:
    mov $0x0000e820, %eax
    mov $0x534d4150, %edx
    mov $20, %ecx
    int $0x15
    jc fail
    add $20, %di
    incl 0x8000
    cmp $0, %ebx
    jnz do_detect

/* for fully using the space, moving kernel to 0x0 when no bios intr needed */
move_kernel:
    cli
    mov $0, %ax
    mov %ax, %es
    mov $0x1000, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds
    mov $0x8000, %cx
    xor %si, %si
    xor %di, %di
    rep
    movsw
    mov %ax, %es
    add $0x1000, %ax
    mov %ax, %ds
    mov $0x8000, %cx
    xor %si, %si
    xor %di, %di
    rep
    movsw


enable_A20:
    in $0x92, %al
    test $0x2, %al
    jnz after
    or $0x2, %al
    and $0xfe, %al
    out %al, $0x92
after:
    jmp enter_protect


fail:
    mov $17, %cx
    mov $msg_fail, %ax
    call print_msg
die:    
    hlt
    jmp die

/* =====================================================
 *   real mode print, use bios int 0x10, ax = 0x1301
 *   %ax: string pointer
 *   %cx: character numbers
 * ===================================================== */
print_msg:
    push %ax
    push %cx

    /* read cursor position (ah = 0x03) */
    mov $0x03, %ah
    xor %bh, %bh
    int $0x10
    jc die

    pop %cx
    pop %ax

    mov $0x7, %bx           /* character attribution */
    mov %ax, %bp
    mov $0x1301, %ax
    int $0x10
    jc die
    ret

enter_protect:
    cli
    lgdt gdt_48
    mov $0x0001, %ax
    lmsw %ax
    jmp $0x8, $enter_kernel         /* clear pipe-line */

    .code32
enter_kernel:
    jmp 0

boot_dirver:
    .byte 0x0

msg_boot:
    .ascii "Loading system ...\r\n"

msg_fail:
    .ascii "Booting failed!\r\n"

packet:
packet.size:
    .byte 0x10
packet.reserved:
    .byte 0x0
packet.nr_block:
    .word 0x0080                    
packet.destination:
packet.destination.offset:  
    .word 0x0000
packet.destination.segment: 
    .word 0x1000
packet.start:
    .word 0x0001, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0

gdt_start:
    .word 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0

    /* code seg discriptor, 0 ~ 4GB*/
    .word 0xffff
    .word 0x0000
    .word 0x9a00
    .word 0x00cf

    /* data seg discriptor, 0 ~ 4GB */
    .word 0xffff
    .word 0x0000
    .word 0x9200
    .word 0x00cf
gdt_end:

gdt_48:
    .word gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    .long gdt_start

    .org 510
    .word 0xaa55
```

If there is no problem, it should jump to 0x9001c(0x9000:go) after the jump instruction, but it jump to the 0x0001c.
Here is the gdb output:

```
0x0000fff0 in ?? ()
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7c00
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, 0x00007c00 in ?? ()
(gdb) b *0x7c17
Breakpoint 2 at 0x7c17
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, 0x00007c17 in ?? ()
(gdb) x/4i 0x7c17
=> 0x7c17:      ljmp   $0x42b4,$0x9000001c
   0x7c1e:      mov    (%esi),%dl
   0x7c20:      flds   (%eax)
   0x7c22:      mov    $0x13cd00ff,%esi
(gdb) x/10b 0x7c17
0x7c17: 0xea    0x1c    0x00    0x00    0x90    0xb4    0x42    0x8a
0x7c1f: 0x16    0xd9
(gdb) x/4i 0x9001c
   0x9001c:     mov    $0x42,%ah
   0x9001e:     mov    (%esi),%dl
   0x90020:     flds   (%eax)
   0x90022:     mov    $0x13cd00ff,%esi
(gdb) ni
0x0000001c in ?? ()

(gdb)
```

The `jmp $0x9000, $go` was translated into `ea 001c 9000`, which seems to be no problem, but
it got wrong result. 
emulator: qemu_system_i386
debug launch commond:

```
    qemu-system-i386 -s -S -hda build/myos.img -m 16M & \
    gdb \
    -ex "target remote localhost:1234" \
    -ex "b *0x7c00" \
    -ex "c"
```

Comment: `p $eip` probably ignores the code segment. Are you sure the actual machine isn't reading instructions from 9000h:001Ch?

Comment: Do you really have the instruction `mov %ax, %cs`? That's not a legal instruction. The assembler should have given an error. It will #UD if it is executed. And of course you don't need to load CS because the far jump instruction already did it.

Comment: GDB doesn't really know about segmentation.  The built-in debugger in Bochs does; it's generally recommended for debugging anything involving segments.

Comment: @prl, you are right, it's my mistake. But it can't explain the problem mentioned above since it didn't run into this instruction before and after I corrected the it.

Comment: You wrote "the $eip got the wrong position". It's not clear that you understand that the correct value in the EIP register after the jump is 0x1c. The CS register contains 0x9000.

Comment: The disassembly shown by gdb at 9001c is incorrect because gdb only understands 32-bit mode. The instruction at 90022 is mov si, ff and the instruction at 90025 is int 13.

Comment: @ecm, thanks to your answer, I find out the problem. The code did run into the right place while the gdb gives the confusing EIP value without according to the segment. The wrong is that I put the bootsector's compile address at 0x0, it makes the wrong address references of some values, and it causes error. Then I make the compile address at 0x7c00, and move bootsector to 0x97c00, it finally works. Thanks again !

Comment: @prl, thanks to your answer, I find out the problem. The code did run into the right place while the gdb gives the confusing EIP value without according to the segment. The wrong is that I put the bootsector's compile address at 0x0, it makes the wrong address references of some values, and it causes error. Then I make the compile address at 0x7c00, and move bootsector to 0x97c00, it finally works. Thanks again !

Comment: @prl, But it's confusing why it runs into the `int 0x13` so fast just with fewer `ni` command.

Comment: EIP *is* the offset part of the CS:EIP logical address.  They're separate registers.  You didn't ask GDB to print the full logical or linear address that code-fetch will happen at (IDK if that's possible), you only asked it to print EIP, so it did.

Comment: Note that the EBDA (Extended BIOS Data Area) is "a variable number of KiB ending at 0x0009FFFF"; so there's no guarantee that relocating your code to 0x00090000 won't corrupt needed BIOS data. In theory you'd want to use `int 0x12` to determine if it's safe, but in practice it's more fun to relocate to a lower address like 0x00001000.